# Android makes my game reload after return from background

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, webview, sandbox

my game has a background controller that decides how long after the app is in the BG it should reload.
but it seems there's a bug in android that kills a process and makes the game restart.
the log is:

```
11-02 11:05:14.725  1619  4874 I ActivityManager: Process com.google.android.webview:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:0 (pid 9665) has died: 
11-02 11:05:14.866  1619  2222 W ActivityManager: Exception when unbinding service com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.ipcservers.background.BackgroundGrpcServerAndroidService
11-02 11:05:14.866  1619  2222 W ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
```

help will be very much appreciated.

thanks

it seems it only happens after pausing and resuming the app a bunch of times, but it doesnt seem to be a memory problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is common behaviour in android, you have to either store the information needed for the moment the game comes back to be in use or use something like

```
Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
```

To prevent the phone goes to standby mode if thats the issue, but still sending the app to background will probably make same effect if you dont store the data needed to coma back.

Comment: thanks for the response, as I was saying-, I have a BG manager, that stores everything, the problem is with this "Sandbox" that dies and kills everything with it. the phone never got into the standby mode.

Comment: Ah, Im sorry I understood it wrong then, Im not sure about this, I see same behaviour iin other apps in android like sometimes you can put them to background and when they come back they know what you were doing and others just show up like just opened them. My personal approach would be to save to memory the data you need to come back when the game is set to background, that way you can restore from memory always, so when you come back you read the data stored in memory instead of using the temporary data the process had